# Does vehicle information count as personal data?

Tags: european-union, vehicle, gdpr

Does a car’s registration number count as personal data under the EU’s General Data Protection Regulation?

How about the VIN? (Vehicle Identification Number)

Comment: If there is an available database, say a governmental one, that connects VINs or registration numbers to owner identities, wouldn't that make the VIN/Reg no a way to indirectly identify the owner, and thus personal information? I am not sure of this, which is why i make this a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @DavidSiegel Yes, I agree. There was a similar discussion about [phone numbers](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/27802/18215). In [C‑582/14](http://curia.europa.eu/juris/celex.jsf?celex=62014CJ0582&lang1=en&type=TXT&ancre=) the CJEU basically says that it does not matter how restrictive it is to identify the owner, if it is possible by law to get it, it constitutes a ‘reasonable means'. See also the text starting at the bottom of page 90 of the [Handbook on European data protection law](https://publications.europa.eu/en/publication-detail/-/publication/5b0cfa83-63f3-11e8-ab9c-01aa75ed71a1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understand it the registration number and VIN are both information about a vehicle and not about a person, and therefore on their own would not qualify as personal data under GDPR.

Vehicle owner information such as name, address etc would be classed as personal data if stored/processed, as would driver information such as license details, endorsements, captured photos/CCTV where the driver can be identified etc.

For reference the definition of 'personal data' in GDPR is:

> "(1) 'personal data' means any information **relating to an identified or identifiable natural person ('data subject')**; an identifiable natural person is one who can be identified, directly or indirectly, in particular by reference to an identifier such as a name, an identification number, location data, an online identifier or to one or more factors specific to the physical, physiological, genetic, mental, economic, cultural or social identity of that natural person;"
>
> [EU General Data Protection Regulations (GDPR)](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/PDF/?uri=CELEX:32016R0679) Article 4 ('Definitions') Paragraph 1, p.33

Answer (score 6):

In Germany it's not so clear:

https://www.lfd.niedersachsen.de/themen/datenschutz_im_kfz/kfz-und-datenschutz-148981.html

> The situation is different with regard to personal data collected in
>   connection with the vehicle. Data is personal if it relates to a
>   "specific person" or at least to an "identifiable person". A person is
>   "identifiable" if, for example, he or she can be identified via the
>   vehicle identification number or other additional knowledge. The
>   Federal Data Protection Act (BDSG) therefore applies in these cases.
>   The BDSG in turn contains a clear statement: the data "belong" to the
>   data subject. Related to the motor vehicle: The data "belong" to the
>   driver or owner of the vehicle.